# Images constructed from dataset rotated

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am not very experienced with python plotting. I want to work with YaleB_32x32 dataset (https://github.com/flatironinstitute/online_psp/blob/master/datasets/YaleB_32x32.mat). This is my code :

```
imgData = scipy.io.loadmat('/path/YaleB_32x32.mat')
matX = imgData['fea']
plt.figure(figsize = (6,6))
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(6, 6)
gs1.update(wspace=0.01, hspace=0.01)
for i in range(36):
    vecX = matX[i,:].reshape(32,32)
    ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[i])
    plt.imshow(vecX, cmap = 'gray')
    plt.axis('off')
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDFQQ.png) is the output.
As you can see that images are rotated. Could someone please help me with where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`rot90`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) to rotate faces with `numpy` lib. Use `axes=(1, 0)` to rotate clockwise:

```py
vecX = np.rot90(matX[i,:].reshape(32, 32), axes=(1, 0))
```

**Edit**
With @bitastap comment, I realize that `reshape` operation needs `Fortan style order` :

```py
vecX = matX[i,:].reshape((32, 32), order='F')
```

Comment: I was wondering if there is a solution without rotating explicitly..because I am worried I am not understanding the matrices properly which might skew later calculations.